# Problem with \cdashline and package arydshln

Tags: errors, packages, punctuation, matrices, arydshln

I have a problem with `\cdashline`. I use the `\cdashline` in a matrix but I have an error with `\usepackage{arydshln}` I think:

```
! Use of \x doesn't match its definition.
\LT@array ->\adl@arrayinit 
                           \adl@LTfirstpagetrue \let \adl@discard \relax \le...
l.5034 }{}
```

If I remove `\usepackage{arydshln}` latex will not stack but it will not recognize `\cdashline`. The strange thing is that package and `\cdashline` works at my pc at home (Windows environment and Miktex tool) but is not working from ubuntu in work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{llp{6.5cm}}
\textbf{System} & \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Tokens included in class} \\
~ & ~ & \\
\cdashline{2-3}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{pifont} 
\usepackage{arydshln}

 \begin{longtable}{llp{6.5cm}}  
    \textbf{System} & \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Tokens included in class} \    ~ & ~ & \\ \cdashline{2-3}

\end{longtable}

\end{document}

Comment: I've added the code in your question. See if it is what you meant.

Answer (score 4):

I found the error. I have added by mistake another `\usepackage{longtable}`.
I read about `arydshln` that it should be added after `\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}`. 
I hope it will help someone.

Comment: I also have this problem, but the problem is not resolved adding \usepackage{tabularx} \usepackage{longtable} first then adding \usepackage{arydshln} later. Do you know the solution?

Comment: `arydshln` must also be included after `makecell`!