# How to create vertical and horizontal dotted lines in a matrix?

Tags: math-mode, matrices, rules, tabularx, arrays

Similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79134/a-matrix-with-labels-dashed-lines), I am trying to output a similar matrix with dotted line instead of dashed line.

[image]

1. Is there anyway to do this?
2. I also try to use these three packages:

   ```
   \usepackage{tabularx}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{arydshln}
   ```
3. I also like to learn how to implement this in **\documentclass{revtex4}**, in addition to using in **\documentclass{article}**. As far as we know that arydshln may not be compatible with revtex4 or revtex4-1 as far as I tried.

[I encounter a problem like this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129166/problem-with-cdashline-and-package-arydshln). And I add `arydshln` after the `tabularx`; but it cannot compile successfully, but only output errors. Could someone offer any hints or some resolutions?

The answer needs not to be complete. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: If there is no dotted lines but only dashed lines, then that is still fine as long as you can offer comments how the problem 2. can be resolved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since `revtex4` seems to be incompatible with the `arydshln` package, here's an option using TikZ:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\Biggl(\mkern-5mu
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.65ex]
\matrix[
  matrix of math nodes,
  column sep=1ex,
] (m)
{
B & C \\
D & E \\
};
\draw[dotted]
  ([xshift=0.5ex]m-1-1.north east) -- ([xshift=0.5ex]m-2-1.south east);
\draw[dotted]
  (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-2.south east);
\node[above,text depth=1pt] at (m-1-1.north) {$\scriptstyle r$};  
\node[above,text depth=1pt] at (m-1-2.north) {$\scriptstyle n-r$};
\node[left,overlay] at ([xshift=-1.2ex]m-1-1.west) {$\scriptstyle r$};
\node[left,overlay] at ([xshift=-1.2ex]m-2-1.west) {$\scriptstyle n-r$};
\end{tikzpicture}\mkern-5mu
\Biggr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo, +1, I am betting that your method works. Please let me try.

Comment: i like this, but the vertical line seems a bit long both above and below (relative to the size of the parentheses), and the two expressions at the top have different baselines. ???

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I fixed the issues with the parentheses and the dotted lines and with the base lines.

Comment: @Idear I'd suggest you to edit your question and add there the information about the document class you are using (`revtex4`) so it becomes clear for everyone what the problem is with trying to use `arydshln`.

Answer (score 14):

You can adjust the dash and gap of the `\hdashline` by modifying the lengths `\dashlinedash` and `\dashlinegap`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{arydshln,leftidx,mathtools}

\setlength{\dashlinedash}{.4pt}
\setlength{\dashlinegap}{.8pt}

\begin{document}
\[
  \leftidx{_{m-r}^{\phantom{m-r}\llap{$\scriptstyle r$}}}{\left( \begin{array}{c:c}
    \smash{\overset{r}{B}} & \mathclap{\smash{\overset{n-r}{C}}} \\
    \hdashline
    D & E
  \end{array} \right)}{}
\]

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X:X}
  \hdashline
  ABC & DEF \\
  \hdashline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

The default for both of the lengths is `4pt`.

Comment: Your answer is nice, I like it very much. I just find that the incompatibility is due to the documentclass, where mine case is \documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4}; but yours is \documentclass{article}. Do you know why my \documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,nofootinbib,superscriptaddress,floatfix]{revtex4} is not compatible with the \usepackage{arydshln,leftidx,mathtools}?

Comment: @Idear: This is why you should *always* post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Not sometimes, but *always*. Why use `revtex4` and not `revtex4-1`?

Answer (score 7):

This uses a stacking approach.  This answer is helping me to think of ways to automate dotted/dashed lines as part of stacks, which in this MWE, had to be done very manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\stackMath
% DASHED LINE OF SPECIFIED LENGTH
% From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
% how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .5em{\rule{.4ex}{.4pt}}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}
\newlength\tmplen
\begin{document}
\[
\strutshortanchors{F}\def\stackalignment{r}\setstackgap{S}{5pt}
\stackanchor[15pt]{{}^r}{{}_{m-r}}
\def\stackalignment{c}
\stackon[1pt]{
  \left(\raisebox{2pt}{%
  \savestack{\num}{$~B~\,$}\tmplen=\wd\numcontent\relax%
  \stackunder{\stackon{\dashline{\tmplen}}{\num}}{D\;}%
  \rotatebox{90}{\kern-1.1\baselineskip\dashline{2.5\baselineskip}}%
  \savestack{\num}{$\,~C~$}\tmplen=\wd\numcontent\relax%
  \stackunder{\stackon{\dashline{\tmplen}}{\num}}{\,E}}%
  \right)
}{%
  ~~{}_r~\,~_{n-r}%
}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The package `nicematrix` has features to do that directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{code-for-first-row = \scriptstyle,code-for-first-col = \scriptstyle }

$A = \begin{pNiceArray}{c:c}[first-row, first-col, columns-width=auto]
    & r & n-r \\
r   & B & C \\
\hdottedline
m-r & D & E 
\end{pNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: many thanks +1!!