# Partitioned in block matrices related

Tags: arrays

How to draw the following block matrix.

[image]

Comment: Possibly related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171518/how-to-create-vertical-and-horizontal-dotted-lines-in-a-matrix, to include the row/column labels

Comment: it'd be absolutely smashing if you could show us what you've tried so far so that we have something to work from; starting from scratch is ok when there's nothing else to do, but otherwise, it's not much fun

Comment: I am sorry but I dont know anything

Comment: Some people take exception to questions of the form "Please draw this for me". You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).