# How to place a vertical dashed line between columns of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

[image: Can you help me how to do that dashed line on this matrix ?]

Can you help me how to do that dashed line on this matrix

Comment: Might be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171518/how-to-create-vertical-and-horizontal-dotted-lines-in-a-matrix?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: i think right-alignment would look better here.  and i've changed the title to make it more useful to someone else looking for information.

Comment: `nicematrix`does a very good job and it is easy to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will add another simple solution if you like.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[ \left[
\begin{array}{c:c}
1 &  2 \\ 
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6 \\ 
\end{array} \right] \]
\end{document}
```

ADDENDUM: 2020-7-24. Using `{bNiceArray}` of `nicematrix` package you will have the square brackets at the same position as in `{bmatrix}` of `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\NiceMatrixOptions{letter-for-dotted-lines=V}

\begin{document}
$\begin{bNiceArray}{c:c}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
5 & 6
\end{bNiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

Remark: If you don't put `\NiceMatrixOptions{letter-for-dotted-lines=V}`, you will have a dotted line (drawn by `nicematrix`).

[image: Result of the second code]

Comment: The dashes are of different lengths which is more or less inevitable if you have long dashes.  Is it possible to make them shorter and more tightly packed?

Comment: Instead of `\left[\begin{NiceArray}...\end{NiceArray}\right]`, it's possible to use `\begin{bNiceArray}...\end{bNiceArray}` with the same result (which is a result similar to `{bmatrix}` of `amsmath`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny Very kind F. Pantigny you are right totally. The reason of my addendum is the same: I'm using https://www.papeeria.com/ that can compile with your previous version of  `nicematrix `(I use the most recent TeXlive2019). Please, can you edit my addenudum adding your screenshot? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano: I have edited your addendum :-)

Comment: @F.Pantigny Excellent. Always thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\left[
    \begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}c}
        -2 & -4 \\
         2 & -1 \\
        -8 & 16
    \end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

To obtain

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me; it (TeXStudio) says: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (;): c' used. \begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}c}
Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (2pt/2pt):c' used. \begin{array}{c;{2pt/2pt}c}

Comment: @AlexKonnen works fine here. add a `MWE` and I'll try to see what happens.

Comment: I have found the reason why it did not work: my document included \usepackage{tabularx}; I assume that \usepackage{arydshln} is somehow incompatible with the latter; if I remove tabularx, the code works, with tabularx it does not.

Comment: The vertical dashes seem to end with a short bold dash. Can this be avoided?

Comment: You can try to modify the option of the dashed line. Here I set 2pt / 2pt.

Answer (score 1):

In the environments of `nicematrix` (eg `{bNiceArray}`), the specifier `|` in the preamble has an optional argument between square brackets. In this argument, it's possible to specify the TikZ characteristics you wish for your rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz=densely dashed]c}
-2 & -4 \\
2  & -1 \\
-8 & 16 \\
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

In this case, the better will probably be better with a `dash phase`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceArray}{c|[tikz={densely dashed,dash phase=3pt}]c}
-2 & -4 \\
2  & -1 \\
-8 & 16 \\
\end{bNiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]